# Problems Running Jenkins, Maven and QA Tools (PMD, Checkstyle and Findbugs)

Tags: maven, jenkins, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

I'm trying to call **Maven** from my **Jenkins CI Server**, while running QA Tools before build process completition, unsuccessfully...

Inside Jenkins' **Invoke top-level Maven targets**, **Goals**, I wrote:

```
-X
-DgroupId=com.mycompany.myapp
-DartifactId=myapp
-Dpackage=com.mycompany.myapp
-Dversion=1.0
checkstyle:checkstyle
pmd:pmd
findbugs:findbugs
compile
package
```

Here's my **console output**:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /root/.jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace
Updating http://x.y.z.w/repos/...
At revision 259

...

[workspace] $ /root/.jenkins/tools/_ci_home_apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn -f /home/ci/workspace/pom.xml -X -DgroupId=com.mycompany.myapp -DartifactId=myapp -Dpackage=com.mycompany.myapp -Dversion=1.0 checkstyle:checkstyle pmd:pmd findbugs:findbugs compile package
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 06:44:56-0200)
Maven home: /root/.jenkins/tools/_ci_home_apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_02, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.2-1.fc16.i686", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /root/.jenkins/tools/_ci_home_apache-maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /root/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /root/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /root/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.mycompany.myapp:myapp:ear:1.0: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging ear from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mycompany.myapp:myapp:ear:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin is missing. @ line 34, column 10
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 26, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 47, column 10
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin is missing. @ line 64, column 9
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

...

[DEBUG] Before: rulesets/basic.xml After: basic.xml
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: Exception when looking for 'rulesets/basic.xml' at ''
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: rulesets/basic.xml
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.getResource(URLResourceLoader.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResourceAsFile(DefaultResourceManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.generateReport(PmdReport.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.execute(PmdReport.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executeReport(PmdReport.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: Exception when looking for 'rulesets/basic.xml
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: rulesets/basic.xml
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.getResource(URLResourceLoader.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResourceAsFile(DefaultResourceManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.generateReport(PmdReport.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.execute(PmdReport.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executeReport(PmdReport.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/basic.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/basic.xml' was found as jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/pmd/pmd/4.3/pmd-4.3.jar!/rulesets/basic.xml.
[DEBUG] Preparing ruleset: rulesets/unusedcode.xml
[DEBUG] Before: rulesets/unusedcode.xml After: unusedcode.xml
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: Exception when looking for 'rulesets/unusedcode.xml' at ''
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: rulesets/unusedcode.xml
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.getResource(URLResourceLoader.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResourceAsFile(DefaultResourceManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.generateReport(PmdReport.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.execute(PmdReport.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executeReport(PmdReport.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: Exception when looking for 'rulesets/unusedcode.xml
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: rulesets/unusedcode.xml
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.getResource(URLResourceLoader.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResourceAsFile(DefaultResourceManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.generateReport(PmdReport.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.execute(PmdReport.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executeReport(PmdReport.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/unusedcode.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/unusedcode.xml' was found as jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/pmd/pmd/4.3/pmd-4.3.jar!/rulesets/unusedcode.xml.
[DEBUG] Preparing ruleset: rulesets/imports.xml
[DEBUG] Before: rulesets/imports.xml After: imports.xml
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: Exception when looking for 'rulesets/imports.xml' at ''
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: rulesets/imports.xml
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.getResource(URLResourceLoader.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResourceAsFile(DefaultResourceManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.generateReport(PmdReport.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.execute(PmdReport.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executeReport(PmdReport.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: Exception when looking for 'rulesets/imports.xml
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: rulesets/imports.xml
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.getResource(URLResourceLoader.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResourceAsFile(DefaultResourceManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.generateReport(PmdReport.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.execute(PmdReport.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executeReport(PmdReport.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/imports.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/imports.xml' was found as jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/pmd/pmd/4.3/pmd-4.3.jar!/rulesets/imports.xml.
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED

...

[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

...

[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

...

[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] No files found in /root/.jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace for pattern: myapp/reports/checkstyle-result.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #32
[FINDBUGS] Collecting findbugs analysis files...
[FINDBUGS] No files found in /root/.jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace for pattern: myapp/reports/findbugs-result.xml
[FINDBUGS] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #32
[PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
[PMD] No files found in /root/.jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace for pattern: myapp/reports/pmd-result.xml
```

And here is **my environment**:

```
Fedora Linux 16
Java 1.7
Jenkins 1.450
Maven 3.0.4
PMD 4.3
Checkstyle 5.5
Findbugs 2.0.0
```

I'm polling a remote SVN repo.

What should I do, in order to **complete build process** running Maven, running QA tools, generating an .ear file and getting QA reports?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you compile the project manually outside of Jenkins on your machine? Also, try to first exclude the QA tools and see if it is working.

Comment: Did you tried to select the exact version of the plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PMD ruleset file are note found. Basic ruleset is used by default ruleset : 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/pmd/faq.html#disable-select-files

```
maven.pmd.rulesetfiles = rulesets/basic.xml,rulesets/unusedcode.xml,rulesets/imports.xml*
```

They are bundled with pmd, and therfore by maven-pmd-plugin.

You can probably link it to your configuration, because you didn't mention the plugin version (you should ever specify it in order to reproduce over the time your builds). I'm not sure it will be sufficient, but if Maven told it to you ... just do it :)

Moreover, simply use goals package (it implies compile).

```
 package pmd:pmd ...
```

And, in order to find out your problme quicker, run the command locally (as sebi advised  you).

Did you mentionned plugin configuration in reporting section, in your pom.xml ?